# output similar images in a directory after comparison with the inputed image in php

Tags: php, html, rgb

In my web page  a user will upload an image then after submit it should be compared with  all  images in a directory and output similar images. I did this with md5 but it will output only exact images and I know the reason but I don't know how to loop all images in my directory with the inputted image using RGB comparisons... Can somebody please help me. Here is my current code:

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $filepath=pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']) ;
    $extension=$filepath['extension'];
    
    $iname= date('H-i-s').'.'.$extension;
    $path='upload/'.$iname;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path)){
        $img=$path;
        echo $img;
        $f=md5(file_get_contents($img));
        $images=glob("img/*");
        foreach($images as $image){
            if($f==md5(file_get_contents($image))){
                echo  "<img height='70px' width='70px' src='".$image."'/>";
            }

        }


    
}
}
?>
```

And my html code

```
    <html>
     <body> 
       <form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type=file name=file><br><input type=submit name=submit value=submit>
       </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write algorithm to compare images and find _similar_ ones? That's like _a lot of work_ and should be paid for.

Comment: Define "similar"...sounds very subjective to me. Might this be a job for a machine learning solution, I wonder

Comment: If it is perfectly the same, it can be done with md5, else it is too complicated for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the class mentioned in this git repo that calculates the image hashes and their differences.

https://github.com/nvthaovn/CompareImage

and changed my code to this:

```
<?php 
include('compareImages.php');
$flag = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $filepath = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $extension = $filepath['extension'];
    
    $iname = date('H-i-s').'.'.$extension;
    $path = 'upload/'.$iname;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        
        $compareMachine = new compareImages($path);
        $images = glob("img/*");

        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            $diff = $compareMachine->compareWith($image);
            
            if($diff < 21) {
                $results[] = $image;
                echo  "<img height='70px' width='70px' src='".$image."'/>";
            }
        }
        
        $flag = 1;
    }
}
```